# Exception Specification more or less restrictive

Tags: c++

Based on [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm)

> Incidentally, you can do this kind of assignment of a pointer to a
>   function as long as the target’s exception specification is no more
>   restrictive than the source’s

```
class A{};
class B{};
class C{};

void f() throw(A,B,C) {}

void (*pf)() throw(A,B);

int main()
{
    pf = f; // pf is more restrictive than that of f. I expect an error here!
}
```

The last statement should not pass the compiler. However, I have tried VS2010 and GCC latest version. Neither or them complain about it.

Question> Why?

Comment: VC++ doesn't enforce exception specifications anyway, so it makes no difference there. Don't know about gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in GCC and VS2010. Clang won't compile it, and it should not compile according to `[except.spec]/5`:

> ... A similar restriction applies to assignment to and initialization of pointers to functions, pointers to member functions, and references to functions: the target entity shall allow at least the exceptions allowed by the source value in the assignment or initialization.

The standard also includes the following example:

```
class A { /*...*/ };
void (*pf1)(); // no exception specification
void (*pf2)() throw(A);
void f() {
    pf1 = pf2; // OK: pf1 is less restrictive
    pf2 = pf1; // error: pf2 is more restrictive
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a long-standing bug in g++: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12255

> The underlying issue is that G++ just ignores exception-specifications on
>   non-function declarations.  I think this choice originated in the uncertainty
>   about whether or not the exeception-specification would become part of a
>   function type rather than remain associated with the declaration.

It wouldn't surprise me if VS was similar in this regard.